# How to get a Raspberry Pi B temperature as a Python3 variable?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there any way to get the temperature of a Raspberry Pi, specifically the B model as a Python3 variable.

The current OS is Raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the onboard Sensor on my RPi, but according to [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=34994), you require this line:
`/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp`

Keep in mind that this doesn't provide a float (as I had previously thought). However, you can use the `subprocess` module to acquire the data and format/strip it from there:

```
import subprocess
temp = subprocess.check_output(["/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | cut -c6-9"], shell=True)[:-1]
```

I have read that using subprocess.Popen() is a better approach - failed to find out why though (perhaps someone else can elaborate on this?).

It would look something like this:

```
tmp = subprocess.Popen(["/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd", "measure_temp"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You can read up more on the `subprocess` module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

**Edit**:
I've updated the code; I recently found a pyscript returning the temperature of the RPi.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll test it out when I next get the chance :)

Comment: Did that work for you? If so, please accept the answer, or let me know if I can help you further.